# How to make a readonly input field editable on the bases of dropdown option's value

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am working on a ONLINE Order System using visual studio as framework and asp classic and vb.net as languages combined with html and javascript. I want to make input fields of a HTML form readonly and editable on the bases of selected value of a drop down list.My code is

```
<table border="0" width="61.2%" align=center><tr ><td  colspan=2  id="bg_page_title"                                   align="center" valign="middle"><strong>
Product Edit Wizard
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" width="50%"><b>Product Name:</b></td> 
<tr>
<td align="right" width="50%"><b>What You Want To Do:</b></td>
 <td width="50%">
 <select name="what_change" id="ma" onChange="changetextbox()" >

<option value="0"> Select Option</option>
<option value="1"  > Bonus Changed</option>
<option value="2"  > Price Changed</option>
<option value="3"  > Product Discontinue</option>
<option value="4"  > Product Re-Open</option>

 </select>
</td></tr> <tr id=Tr1>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Fact Price:</b></td>
<td width="50%">
<tr id=Tr1>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Fact Price:</b></td>
<td width="50%">
<input  type="text" id="ma" name="f_price" value="<%=rs("f_price")%>"  > </td>
</tr>
<tr id=Tr2>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Dist Price:</b></td>
<td width="50%" ><input  type="text" id="ma" name="d_price" value="<%=rs("d_price")%>"   >   </td>
</tr>
<tr id=Tr3>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Flat Rate:</b></td>
<td width="50%" ><input   type="text" id="ma" name="bonus_rate" value="     <%=rs("bonus_rate")%>"  </td>
</tr>
<tr id=Tr4>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Scheme:</b></td>
<td width="50%" ><input type="text" id="ma" name="bonus_sch"  value="  <%=rs("bonus_sch")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr id=Tr5>
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Units:</b></td>
<td width="50%" ><input  type="text" id="ma" name="bonus_units"  value="<%=rs("bonus_units")%>" > </td></tr>
```

I want to do that when user select 'bonus change" only relevant fields of bonus will editable and others will remain readonly. and when user select "price change" only relevant fields of price will be editable and other will change to readonly. Kindly guide me to solve my problem.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

at first change ids  of input fields, id must be unique, use Jquery to do that, something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#select_box_id").change(function(){

        $("input[type='text']").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(".ma"+$(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled');
  })
})


<table border="0" width="61.2%" align=center><tr ><td  colspan=2  id="bg_page_title"                                   align="center" valign="middle"><strong>
Product Edit Wizard
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" width="50%"><b>Product Name:</b></td> 
<tr>
<td align="right" width="50%"><b>What You Want To Do:</b></td>
 <td width="50%">
 <select name="what_change" id="select_box_id" onChange="changetextbox()" >

<option value="0"> Select Option</option>
<option value="1"  > Bonus Changed</option>
<option value="2"  > Price Changed</option>
<option value="3"  > Product Discontinue</option>
<option value="4"  > Product Re-Open</option>

 </select>
</td></tr> <tr id="Tr1">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Fact Price:</b></td>
<td width="50%">
<tr id="Tr1">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Fact Price:</b></td>
<td width="50%">
    <input  type="text" class="ma2" name="f_price" value=""  /> </td>
</tr>
<tr id="Tr2">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Ex-Dist Price:</b></td>
    <td width="50%" ><input  type="text" class="ma2" name="d_price" value=""  />   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="Tr3">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Flat Rate:</b></td>
    <td width="50%" ><input   type="text" class="ma1" name="bonus_rate" value=""/>  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="Tr4">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Scheme:</b></td>
    <td width="50%" ><input type="text" class="ma1" name="bonus_sch"  value="" /> </td></tr>
<tr id="Tr5">
<td align="right" width="50%" ><b>Bonus Units:</b></td>
<td width="50%" ><input  type="text" class="ma1" name="bonus_units"  value=""/> </td></tr>
```

Comment: Thanx dear....can you tell me please where should i write JQuery code in my page...???

Comment: u can put it anywhere you like in script , ata the top , or at the bottom of your html code, just open <script>put it here</script>

Comment: Kindly can you explain how can i get input fields in following lines of code           $(".get_all_input_fields_by_class").attr('disabled','disabled');
                $("#get_the_only_input_field_you_want_to_be_editable").removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: Dear Anulik it works nice in this fiddle but when i try that code in my page it does'nt work...:(

Comment: have you include jquery.js library?, if not downlod it from here http://jquery.com/, and add it itno your <head><script src="path to your downloaded js" type="text/javascript"></script></head> tag

Comment: and don't forget  $(document).ready(function(){ code here  })    http://jsfiddle.net/LJc7g/15/

Comment: kindly tell me where i shoul include the JQuery function and css code in my page...???

Comment: u can put your js code whereever you like in script , ata the top , or at the bottom of your html code, just open <script>put it here</script>                                                        jquery.js and your css files you should includ in the  head        <head><script src="path to your downloaded js" type="text/javascript"></script><link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></head>

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your id's into a unique one(No elements should share the same id).
Simply add a corresponding classes on every input based on what class may be applicable for them. For example:

- Class '1' is for Bonus Change
- Class '2' is for Price Change
- and so on...

`<input  type="text" id="ma" name="d_price" value="<%=rs("d_price")%>" class="1 2">`

Then using JQuery:

```
$("#ma").change(function(){   // "ma": the id of your drop down(select)
   var cls = $(this).val();
   $('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
   $('.'+cls).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: In your case, ids are not necessary, classes do to identify themeselves whether they belong that group

Comment: dear what values have to passed in following lines                             $('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
       $('.'+cls).removeAttr('disabled');